# Compiling a C# with x86 profile in build still receives invalid win32 app

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I wrote a program in C# Windows Forms. I can build the program by using the simple build solution. In the configuration manager I have it set to x86 processor. I am using Visual Studio 2012. I am on a 64 bit machine. I can run the form on 64 bit servers. when I run the form on a 32 bit server, I receive an application error simply stating, "file.exe is not a valid win32 application"

Comment: Well, what does "cannot run" mean? A likely cause is one of the dependencies only supports x64.

Comment: Is there a specific error message?  It's likely one of the .dlls is compiled only for x64 and not x86.

Comment: the windows error is file.exe is not a valid Win32 application.

Comment: If you want help, you'll have to give us more information. What settings have you changed? Are you checking the right output directory (release/debug, maybe)? How are you building your application? Without more info, we can just guess.

Comment: Jim. I use f6 to build the program. There is nothing special about this. I'm trying to explain it the best I can. I changed my main text.

Comment: Does your program build and runs properly when you debug ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Visual Studio Solution Explorer, right-click on your project and select Properties. On the Build tab, make sure that Platform is set to x86.

At the beginning of your program, add code to see if it's running in a 32-bit process:

```
Console.WriteLine("64-bit process = {0}", Environment.Is64BitProcess);
```

(If you have a GUI app, display a message box with that info.)

That should say `false`. If it doesn't say `false`, then you aren't creating a 32-bit application.

If it does say `false` and your application won't run on your 32-bit machine, then it's likely that you're copying the wrong file. Add this line:

```
Console.WriteLine(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase);
```

That'll tell you where the file you're executing is located. Copy from there to your servers.

You say that you're getting a message "file.exe is not a valid win32 application". Just to be certain, the 'file.exe' that it reports is the name of your application, right, and not some other exe or dll that your application depends on?

If you're okay with this application always running as 32-bit, then leaving the platform set to x86 is fine. But you might want to set it to "Any CPU" if you want it to run as 64-bit on machines that support it.

Comment: thanks a lot for your response. i was doing all of that. when i used the calls you mentioned i was able to figure out that in my compiler it was set to .net 4.5 framework. I switched it to 4 and it worked fine on the other servers. so in a nutshell that error was related to the .net compile time version. weird error. thanks again!